# Multiple JW player autoplay issue in Chrome, warnings 334001 and 330000

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I've been trying to add multiple JW players to a single page. The idea is to have several players stretched 100% width of the page and to autoplay videos when users scroll to video containers. Video container height is in 16:9 aspect ratio. I separated video containers by an empty container in DOM (1000px height and red background) for demonstration purposes only. JW player warning codes shown in console are 334001 and 330000. I found out that these errors are new, so they are not documented yet. This wouldn't be a problem, but it stalls the player and shows green background instead of video container. My account is free (developer) type.

At some (almost random) point there is an error shown in Chrome console:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

So I guess that `autostart` and `autoPause` properties in JW player setup aren't working as expected, and maybe custom async handling of video pausing and play could do the trick.

1. JW player library v8.14.0 was downloaded from this location "//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/IDzF9Zmk.js" and included in my project via webpack. Importing library via CDN didn't make make any difference.
2. This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    videoInit();
});

function videoInit() {
    // list of video IDs
    const videos = {
        main: '6BRJEJBJ',
        sky: 'Pmi4Tef0',
        moon: 'Z3w5Ptnu',
        city: 'VHiZEW9S',
        mountains: 'LlY3I9AL',
        villa: 'WMAXC1tw',
    };

    // set thumbnail resolution
    function thumbnailResolution() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 320) {return '320'}
        if (window.innerWidth < 720) {return '720'}
        if (window.innerWidth < 1280) {return '1280'}
        return '1920';
    }

    // inject video containers to the webpage
    Object.values(videos).forEach(el => {
        let videoContainer = document.createElement("DIV");
        videoContainer.id = el;
        document.body.appendChild(videoContainer);

        let videoSeparator = document.createElement("DIV");
        videoSeparator .class = el;
        videoSeparator .style.height = '1000px';
        videoSeparator .style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.body.appendChild(videoSeparator );
    });

    // initialize videos
    Object.values(videos).forEach(el => {
        jwplayer(el).setup({
            file: 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/manifests/' + el + '.m3u8',
            image: 'https://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/' + el + '-' + thumbnailResolution() + '.jpg',
            stretching: 'fill',
            controls: 'false',
            repeat: 'true',
            mute: 'true',
            tracks: [{
                'file': 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/strips/' + el + '-120.vtt',
                'kind': 'thumbnails',
            }],
            autostart: 'viewable',
            autoPause: {
                viewability: true,
                pauseAds: true,
            },
        });
    });
}
```

I tried different browsers:
 1. Chrome v81.0.4044.138 (64-bit), works for a single video, once multiple videos are added, player breaks when you scroll up / down several times (this action plays/pauses videos that are currently visible in the browser window)
 2. Firefox v76.0.1 (64-bit), solution works as expected
 3. Edge and IE11, works, but video thumbnails are shown only once. When you scroll away from, and then back to video container, black background is shown instead of a thumbnail picture.

I also tried disabling webpack HMR.

Answer (score 0):

Tests are performed on different computers and issue was not reproducible, even with same OS and browser version. Issue is probably related to graphic card drivers on my local machine.